# How to link an image and target a new window

Tags: html

I have a picture, if I click onto that picture, how can I build an image reference so another page opens in a new tab or a new window of my browser displaying the picture?

Answer (score 79):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img width="220" height="250" border="0" align="center"  src=""/>
</a>
```

Comment: The `align="center"` part is especially needed if you're building a document which will be converted to a PDF using Rotativa.

Comment: Somehow target attribute is not working in StackOverflow profile. After adding it, the image is not hyperlinked anymore

Comment: On some of the websites when you click on an image it open in new tab and user can enlarge. How to code for that ?

Answer (score 26):

If you use script to navigate to the page, use the `open` method with the target `_blank` to open a new window / tab:

```
<img src="..." alt="..." onclick="window.open('anotherpage.html', '_blank');" />
```

However, if you want search engines to find the page, you should just wrap the image in a regular link instead.

Comment: `onclick="window.open(this.src, '_blank');"`

Answer (score 11):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> //gives blank window
<img width="220" height="250" border="0" align="center"  src=""/> // show image into new window
</a>
```

See the code

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want to show an Image thumbnail which is 50x50 pixels and link to the the actual image you can do

```
<a href="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Image description" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height; 50px; background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');"></a>
```

Of course it's best to give that link a class or id and put it in your css

Answer (score 6):

you can do like this

```
<a href="http://www.w3c.org/" target="_blank">W3C Home Page</a>
```

find this page

```
http://www.corelangs.com/html/links/new-window.html
```

goreb

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple solution

```
<a href="path/of/your/image/image.png" target="_blank">
    <img src="path/of/your/image/image.png" alt=""
        style="width: 37rem;max-width: 100%;height: auto;vertical-align: 
        middle;border-style: none;">
</a>
```

See live https://codepen.io/awaisaslampro/pen/abwOPrP

Answer (score 2):

To open in a new tab use:

```
target = "_blank"
```

To open in the same tab use:

```
target = "_self"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about to click on Image and open in **New Tab** like this [image]

Here is the code:

```
<a href="assets/images/android-chrome-512x512.png" target="_blank">
    <img width="220" height="250" border="0" align="center"  src="assets/images/android-chrome-512x512.png" alt=""/>
  </a>
```

Both the **href and and src** attributes values/URL's can be local for testing and incase of live site.. it should be live link to access

Answer (score 1):

Open image in **New Tab** simply:

```
<img src="" alt="" onclick="window.open(this.src, '_blank');"/>
```