# Can't use <img src=""onclick='window.open('anotherpage.html','_blank");' /> attribute in HTML correctly

Tags: php, html, image

Today I'm trying to use the img attribute code from StacOverflow, but not successfully.

```
<img src="..." alt="..." onclick="window.open('anotherpage.html', '_blank');" />
```

from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139811/how-to-link-an-image-and-target-a-new-window)!

image.php

```
<?php
$pic = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg');
shuffle($pic);
?>
```

original.index.php it works cool

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Random Images</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <?php
include("img/image.php");
       for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
          echo "<li style=\"display: inline;\">
                         <img src=\"$pic[$i]\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\">
                       </li>";

    ?>  
 </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

in.my.case.index.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Random Images</title>
</head>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <?php
include("img/image.php");
       for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
          echo "<li style=\"display: inline;\">
                         <img src=\"$pic[$i]\" width=\"150\" height=\"130\" alt=\"Go to back\" onclick=\"window.open(\"anotherpage.php\", \"_blank\");\" />
                       </li>";

    ?>  
 </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```

do not judge strictly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double quotes for the function arguments as well as around the `onclick` attribute is causing the problem.

Example fix:

```
echo "<li style=\"display: inline;\">
        <img src=\"$pic\" width=\"150\" height=\"130\" alt=\"Go to back\" onclick='window.open(\"anotherpage.php\", \"_blank\");' />
    </li>";
```

It's personal preference, but you might consider this method to be more readable:

```
<?php for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
<li style="display: inline;">
    <img src="<?php echo $pic[$i]; ?>" width="150" height="130" alt="Go to back" onclick='window.open("anotherpage.php", "_blank");' />
</li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replaceing the double quotes with single quotes in the javascript part:

```
onclick=\"window.open('anotherpage.php', '_blank');\" />
```