# ArrayBuffer as source (image tag) / Display image from Blob

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set an arraybuffer as source of an image tag.
It seems that I've got 2 problems. My console is logging:

> GET unsafe:data:image/jpg;base64, [object ArrayBuffer]
>   net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

so my question is:
1. How do I convert my 'blob' to a string?
(if necessary: 2. How to remove the unsafe flag?)

html:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, {{blob}}">
```

ts (blob is transferred):

```
export class ImgViewerComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input('blob') blob: ArrayBuffer;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Are trying to show image from file upload control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay found some good solutions:

1. Converting ArrayBuffer to string:

   > ```
   > function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
   >   var binary = '';
   >   var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
   >   var len = bytes.byteLength;
   >   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   >      binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
   >   }
   >   return window.btoa( binary );
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > [ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string)
2. Remove the unsafe prefix:

   > ```
   > import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
   > ...
   > constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
   > ...
   > sanitize( url:string ) {
   >   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > [How to avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to link by Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432609/how-to-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-link-by-angular2/40784119)

Now my Html looks like the following:

```
<img [src]="sanitize('data:image/jpg;base64, ' + _arrayBufferToBase64(blob))">
```

Comment: Hello, This solution worked for me. But I want to open image or file in another tab, How can i achieve the same using this solution? Thank you.

Comment: @AkshayDusane You can wrap the image tag with href. It'll pass your image to the link as content. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139811/how-to-link-an-image-and-target-a-new-window

Comment: Excellent post. Worked very well! Thank you so much.